# How to migrate 4 milions record in subscribers_table table to separate 40 tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, procedure

I have huge data record in subscribers_table about 4,200,000 records, when I select one user by email it is take long time, now I don't want delete those records and I need to work on seperated tables like subscribers_table1, subscribers_table2, ... , subscribers_table42

Now I need **define procedure in mysql** that move the hole of data in subscribers_table into seperated tables subscribers_table1, subscribers_table2, ..., subscribers_table42
the following code is in pseudo code:

```
table_number = 1
function table_to_migrate_into_separate_tables():
    //this loop to read 100,000 record and move to next 100,000 until the end of table
    for every 100,000 record in subscribers_table:
          //this to create table with nambe (original name + table_number)
          Create table("subscribers_table" + table_number)
          //this to move 100,000 record only to the created table
          Move 100,000 record to table("subscribers_table"+ table_number)
          //increase table number to be unique
          table_number ++
          //this check if subscribers_table has migrate all the records into seperate table then break loop and finish
          if subscribers_table has finish:
                 Break loop
```

Comment: I think it is a very bad solution btw. How do you intend to recover any data in this mess? 4,200,000 is not big enough to screw your system. You should work with indexes or make better decisions in your scheme before try a "solution" like the one you describe here.

Comment: I agree, but this system is working online and I can't modify the code to solve the problem and I need this way to separate them in 42 tables

Comment: You need no such thing.  Do you have an index on the email field?

Comment: @TàrekKala'ajy you can set indexes to your mysql database without downtime in the system. You can run a EXPLAIN query that tells you better ways to solve this problem. Some references: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/ and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: I concur with others that you probably only need a good index here. For more on indexing (and other performance topics), I warmly recommend taking a look at: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) The added benefit is that a new index can be created on-line (as already mentioned by taiar) and without requiring a client code change (which new tables certainly would).

Answer (score 1):

This is called **[Partitionning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html)**, and MySQL can do the job for you:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table PARTITION BY KEY(some_column_here) PARTITIONS 40;
```

However, 4M rows is not *that* large after all, perhaps all you lack is an index on `email`.

Comment: I think Partioning is only useful when u save your records on different physical devices. Indexing the data is the right practice here

Comment: Partitionning allows some [Partition pruning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-pruning.html) optimisation, which means manipulating a smaller data set (and smaller indexes). So it *may* help to some extend. But proper indexing is definitely the most important factor, obviously.